# psutil - getting process name is blank

Tags: python, psutil

I'm trying to run this code and I'm not getting the list of processes by name:

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "python.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name == PROCNAME:
        print proc
```

What I get is nothing even though the process is running.

Comment: This is not really a question. You should just try to print out the process names and see what's happening. If it's a bug, report it to psutil bug tracker. If there's something you can't explain, ask on the psutil list. In this case, I think the process name is something like `C:\Python27\python.exe` (or something similar).

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same problem. Changing `proc.name` to `proc.name()` solved it for me if anyone else was having similar issues.

Comment: thank you, instead of documentation, that how it is really works.
Because `name` returns object, and `_name` is filled with delay, and usually has state `None`. And just `name()` acts as expected.

Answer (score 3):

There have been significant changes in the `psutil` API with version 2.0.0:

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#200---2014-03-10

The `proc.name` class property was replaced by the `proc.name()` method. So you need to adapt this.

Answer (score -1):

Try to see exactly which is the format of the process name served by `psutil`:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print proc.name
```